# How to select Random Sub string,which seperated by coma(",") From a string

Tags: mysql

I have a column which having a list of id's separated by coma, I want to select a random ID from it,

```
    slId  |  adsId
    __________________________
     1    |   1,3,5,6,8,10
     2    |   2,3,4,6,8,9,11
```

I want to select one Random adsId from above Table.

Expected Result:

```
    slId  |  adsId
    _________________
     1    |   5
     2    |   11
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please notice that it's always better not to store comma separated values in your fields. But if you can't change your database structure, you could use this MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  slID,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(adsId, ',', rand()*(LENGTH(adsId)-LENGTH(REPLACE(adsID, ',', '')))+1),
    ',',
    -1) as random_ads
FROM
  yourtable
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23423/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in php.

```
    //retrieve all your adsId for slId 1
$array = explode(',', $resultOfQuery);
$nb = rand(0, sizeof($array));
$value = $array[$nb];
```

Maybe there is a simple way in sql, but i don't know sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the problem is, I'm not using this with php, so I need a mySQL select query for this..

Comment: Ok men, Follow the "fthiella" answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
It will be more simple if you use php code here,

$adsId_array = explode(',', $adsId);
$random_number = rand(0, sizeof($adsId_array));
$value = $array[$random_number];

>> Here $value will return random value every time.
```

Thanks!