# MySQL: select random individual from available to populate new table

Tags: mysql, select, random

I am trying to automate the production of a roster based on leave dates and working preferences.  I have generated some data to work with and I now have two tables - one with a list of individuals and their preferences for working on particular days of the week(e.g. some prefer to work on a Tuesday, others only every other Wednesday, etc), and another with leave dates for individuals.  That looks like this, where `firstpref` and `secondpref` represent weekdays with Mon = 1, Sun = 7 and `firstprefclw` represents a marker for which week of a 2 week pattern someone prefers (0 = no pref, 1 = wk 1 preferred, 2 = wk2 preferred)

`initials | firstpref | firstprefclw | secondpref | secondprefclw
KP | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0
BD | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0
LW | 3 | 0 | 4 | 1`

Then there is a table `leave_entries` which basically has the initials, a start date, and an end date for each leave request.

Finally, there is a pre-calculated `clwdates` table which contains a marker (a `1` or `2`) for each day in one of its columns as to what week of the roster pattern it is.

I have run this query:

```
SELECT @tdate, DATE_FORMAT(@tdate,'%W') AS whatDay, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.initials separator ',') AS available
FROM people AS t1
WHERE ((t1.firstpref = (DAYOFWEEK(@tdate))-1 
AND (t1.firstprefclw = 0 OR (t1.firstprefclw = (SELECT c_dates.clw from clwdates AS c_dates LIMIT i,1)))) 
OR (t1.secondpref = (DAYOFWEEK(@tdate))-1 
AND (t1.secondprefclw = 0 OR (t1.secondprefclw = (SELECT c_dates.clw from clwdates AS c_dates LIMIT i,1)))
OR ((DAYOFWEEK(@tdate))-1 IN (0,5,6))
AND t1.initials NOT IN (SELECT initials FROM leave_entries WHERE @tdate BETWEEN leave_entries.start_date and leave_entries.end_date) 
);
```

My output from that is a list of dates with initials of the pattern:

`2018-01-03;Wednesday;KP,LW,TH`

My desired output is

`2018-01-03;Wednesday;KP`

Where the initials of the person have been randomly selected from the list of available people generated by the first set of `SELECT`s.

I have seen a SO post where a suggestion of how to do this has been made involving `SUBSTRING_INDEX` ([How to select Random Sub string,which seperated by coma(",") From a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837702/how-to-select-random-sub-string-which-seperated-by-coma-from-a-string)), however I note the comment that CSV is not the way to go, and since I have a table which is not CSV, I am wondering:

How can I randomly select an individual's initials from the available ones and create a table which is basically `date ; random_person`?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do it.
The first select (outlined above) forms the heart of a `PROCEDURE` called `ROWPERROW()` and generates a table called `available_people`

This is probably filthy MySQL code, but it works:

```
SET @tdate = 0
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS on_call;
CREATE TABLE working(tdate DATE, whatDay VARCHAR(20), selected VARCHAR(255));
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ROWPERROW2;
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW2()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE kk INT DEFAULT 0;
SET n=90; -- or however many days the roster is going to run for
SET kk=0;
WHILE kk<n DO
SET @tdate = (SELECT c_dates.fulldate from clwdates AS c_dates LIMIT kk,1); 
INSERT INTO working
SELECT @tdate, DATE_FORMAT(@tdate,'%W') AS whatDay, t1.available 
FROM available_people AS t1 -- this is the table created by the first query above
WHERE tdate = @tdate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

SET kk = kk + 1;
END WHILE;
end;
//

DELIMITER ;

CALL ROWPERROW2();

SELECT * from working;
```